# jQuery Tabs Sqeezable tabs like browser (FF, Chrome, Safari)

Tags: jquery-ui

I am using jQuery tabs but my requirement is as tabs increase it should squeeze to available space like Firefox, chrome when tabs count increase more then 9, 10 all tabs squeeze a little & re-adjust accordingly, all next tabs will be smaller by doing this I can open more tabs on my application. Hope I explain my point thanks.

Comment: If you are looking for an existing plugin - where have you looked? If you are trying to roll your own - what have you tried?

Comment: You could do away with the existing [Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/) jQuery-ui widget and some styling (min-width, max-width, css3 flex-layout).

Comment: @Jan Dvorak i am using jquery UI tabs, & looked most of jquery available plug-in but still no success i found next previous arrow type thing where u can see the next opened tabs by clicking the next button but that’s not required.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak flex-layout thats good thing let me play with & let you know please meanwhile if anybody has some example please share thanks.

Comment: 2ndly cannot be handled with min, max width i already tried.

Comment: You could set the width dynamically by Javascript

Comment: flex-layout didn’t work it’s not for flexible tab thing, also i tired fixing the max width but i am not able to get the desire scenario when tabs increase 10+ & previous & next tabs add in short width you know how FF browser tabs work

Comment: how to Upvote? am new to asking questions :p

Comment: You can upvote a question by clicking the up arrow next to the question vote totals. You cannot vote for your own question (or answer).

Comment: still no success please help :(